# What's the difference between df.head() and df.head?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

In Jupyter Notebook or terminal, both df.head and df.head() can return an output of the dataframe, with some minor differences. What's the fundamental difference between the two different expressions and what role does parenthesis play in Python in general?
Thanks!

```
>>>df.head
<bound method NDFrame.head of          Date    Open    High     Low   Close    Volume
0    1-Jun-17  153.17  153.33  152.22  153.18  16404088
1    2-Jun-17  153.58  155.45  152.89  155.45  27770715
2    5-Jun-17  154.34  154.45  153.46  153.93  25331662
3    6-Jun-17  153.90  155.81  153.78  154.45  26624926
4    7-Jun-17  155.02  155.98  154.48  155.37  21069647
5    8-Jun-17  155.25  155.54  154.40  154.99  21250798
6    9-Jun-17  155.19  155.19  146.02  148.98  64882657
7   12-Jun-17  145.74  146.09  142.51  145.42  72307330
8   13-Jun-17  147.16  147.45  145.15  146.59  34165445
9   14-Jun-17  147.50  147.50  143.84  145.16  31531232
10  15-Jun-17  143.32  144.48  142.21  144.29  32165373
>>> df.head()
       Date    Open    High     Low   Close    Volume
0  1-Jun-17  153.17  153.33  152.22  153.18  16404088
1  2-Jun-17  153.58  155.45  152.89  155.45  27770715
2  5-Jun-17  154.34  154.45  153.46  153.93  25331662
3  6-Jun-17  153.90  155.81  153.78  154.45  26624926
4  7-Jun-17  155.02  155.98  154.48  155.37  21069647
```

Answer (score 10):

Those aren't just "minor differences". You didn't actually take the head at all with `df.head`.

`df.head()` actually takes the head of the dataframe. You can see that the output only has 5 rows:

```
>>> df.head()
       Date    Open    High     Low   Close    Volume
0  1-Jun-17  153.17  153.33  152.22  153.18  16404088
1  2-Jun-17  153.58  155.45  152.89  155.45  27770715
2  5-Jun-17  154.34  154.45  153.46  153.93  25331662
3  6-Jun-17  153.90  155.81  153.78  154.45  26624926
4  7-Jun-17  155.02  155.98  154.48  155.37  21069647
```

In contrast, `df.head` is just a method object for the `head` method of the dataframe `df`. The parentheses are needed to actually call the method. The method object's `repr` is basically

```
f"<bound method {classname}.{methodname} of {object!r}"
```

with the class name, method name, and `repr` of the object substituted in the appropriate places. The part of the output that looks like a dataframe is, in fact, the `repr` of the original `df`. It has 10 rows instead of 5 because it's the whole original dataframe, not the head.

Answer (score 5):

`head` return a `method` `head()` return the top 5(default) row in your dataframe

```
type(df.head)
<class 'method'>
type(df.head())
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

Answer (score -1):

Parentheses are used to call a function. Let’s take a small example with `append` just using it without parenthesis on a list will do nothing as it will just return the function itself but using the parenthesis call the function:

```
a = [1]
a.append
print(a)
[1]

a.append(2)
print(a)
[1, 2]

append = a.append
append(3)
print(a)
[1, 2, 3]
```

What you see when just using `head` is similar. They just added some code to actually call the function with default value.